# How to wrap multiple select queries into one query in Mybatis?

Tags: mysql, sql, mybatis

How do I return multiple select queries in MyBatis? for example, I want to return a list of 20 users, the total number of users, say 1000. In the following example, I use SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS to get the total number before LIMIT applies, and use FOUND_ROWS() to retrieve the cached value in the second select query.

```
<resultMap type="User" id="userResultMap">
    <id property="id" column="u_id" />
    <result property="username" column="u_username" />
        <result property="password" column="u_password" />
        <result property="email" column="u_email" />
</resultMap>

<select id="get" parameterType="Integer" resultType="list" resultMap="userResultMap">
        SELECT            
            SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS
            u.id                           AS u_id,
            u.username               AS u_username,
            u.password               AS u_password,
            u.email                     AS u_email
       FROM user u WHERE u.id=#{id}
       <if test="startIndex != null and perPage != null">
            LIMIT #{startIndex}, #{perPage}
       </if>

       SELECT FOUND_ROWS(), #{startIndex}, #{perPage};
</select>
```

I was thinking of adding another resultMap and didn't find a way to take multiple returns in Java Spring side.

In the Java side, it was like

```
List<User> get(@Param("id") Integer id, @Param("startIndex") Integer startIndex,
            @Param("perPage") Integer perPage);
```

Comment: This won't happen in MyBatis. What logic are you applying for which you have to run 2 select queries?

Comment: If it could be done in only 1 select, it is much better. Could it be done in 1 select in my case?

Comment: Why can't you have 2 different <select> tags? 1 for count and other for list of Users. If you can use a separate query for count and are facing the problem of how to return that count value, then here is what you need to do:

<select id="getUsersCount" parameterType="map" resultType="hashmap">
SELECT COUNT(*) USERS_COUNT FROM USER
</select>

In the Java code, you'll get the USERS_COUNT value.

Comment: that's exactly what I am doing now and it works, but I am looking for an optimized solution which one query returns two things.

Comment: We could have tried to achieve that optimised solution IF we could club these 2 select statements. If these statements could be clubbed, then we could have written another resultMap and handle accordingly at the java side but due to COUNT, the queries can't be clubbed.. So, in short, right now, the above solution looks the best.

Comment: I have posted the comment as my answer. I think there can't be any other easier way to achieve what you want to do. If you think that the answer is fine, then mark it correct. :)

Answer (score -1):

You have use 2 different `<select>` tags. 1 for count and other for list of Users. To return the count value, you can use the following:

`<select id="getUsersCount" parameterType="map" resultType="hashmap"
    SELECT COUNT(*) USERS_COUNT FROM USER
</select>`

In the Java code, you'll get the USERS_COUNT value.

Comment: > that's exactly what I am doing now and it works, but I am looking for an optimized solution which one query returns two things. – Daniel Qiu

Comment: have you had any progress on this ? I am struggling with the very same thing here.. https://github.com/mybatis/mybatis-3/issues/274#issuecomment-341648667